# Can I save on a variable some named arguments, in order to reuse it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have many common arguments on some components, so I would like to reuse that, but without needing to create a new Widget just to do that.

For example, on JS/React we could do that:

```
const defaultProps = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
}

<Foo {...defaultProps} />
<Bar {...defaultProps} />
<Baz {...defaultProps} />
```

Is there something similar on Dart/Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class that hold all these properties and use this class in different widgets. For example:

```
class SomeClassWithProps{}

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  final SomeClassWithProps props;
}

class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  final SomeClassWithProps props;
}

class Baz extends StatelessWidget {
  final SomeClassWithProps props;
}
```

And then when you use these widgets you can define the props once and use it in all of them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for, because I would like a solution that need to write less boilerplate, and more flexible than wrapping a widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourCustomClass extends StatelessWidget {
  /// These are the arguments you want to pass in
  /// Note: The parameter can be any data type, Function or Widget
  final Color yourColor;
  final String yourText;

  /// This is your constructor for the class (your custom component)
  /// It basically serves as your blueprint
  /// I used the @required annotation for the first parameter to indicate that parameter must be provided
  YourCustomClass({@required this.yourColor, this.yourText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      /// The color pass in through the constructor will be used here
      color: yourColor,

      /// The String pass in through the constructor will be displayed here
      child: Text(yourText),
    );
  }
}
```

You can now use this StatelessWidget class and pass in the arguments in. So you don't need to write the boilerplate code again. Import the component into the class you need it pass in the arguments and use. Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for, because I would like a solution that need to write less boilerplate, and more flexible that wrapping the widget.